# A Login Site with parameter

Tags: jsf

We have a jsf application, with a normal logon site. Now we have to integrate this application with another and my problem is to pass the parameter between the two applications. Say a client has an ID in one application and I have to load the logon page from the second application and I think the easiest way to inform the second application about the client from the first is to load the login page with a parameter, which is the client ID from the first application.

The other way, my second application must function stand alone, so I need two login pages, one without parameters, one with parameter. It is even possible this way, or there are another way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second application can have single login page with two different forms.

You can pass some ID from 1st application as part of a session attribute and get that session attribute in the login page of second application. Here, you can check if you got the session attribute (is null or not), and render the relevant form as applicable. Instead, if one directly hits the login page of second application, this session attribute won't be there, and you can render the other form as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share session between two different applications . Your strategy to pass the parameter from first to second application seems correct to me.

If you want to share the login then the other way could be to add the login detail in a encrypted cookie in first application and when you redirect to the other application the second application can verify login based on encrypted cookie.

Both application should be running in same domain to accept the cookie (e.g. .xyz.com)

This is how most of the SSO(single sign on) applications share the session by using LTPA token as a cookie.

Comment: It's possible to share session if they run on the same server and domain.

Comment: Can we share the session between two web applications ? My understanding was that some appservers provide this by serializing and de-serializing session between clusters , but that works only on the same application deployed on several clusters.

Comment: As said, it's possible to share session if they run on the same server and domain.